# Eigenvalues of the product of a positive semi-definite matrix with an invertible matrix with positive eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Given a Laplacian matrix of a connected graph, $\mathcal{L} \succeq 0 \in \mathbb{S}^n$, and an invertible matrix $V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that $\lambda_i(V) >0$ for $i = 1, ... ,n$. Is it possible to prove that $\lambda_i(\mathcal{L}V) \geq 0$ for $i = 1, ... ,n$? And can we determine the number of zero eigenvalues of the product?

Comment: I believe it can be shown that $\mathcal L V$ is similar to $\mathcal L^{1/2} V \mathcal L^{1/2}$. However, unless we are additionally given that $V$ is symmetric, I don't know if we can guarantee that $\mathcal L^{1/2} V \mathcal L^{1/2}$ has non-negative eigenvalues

Comment: Correct. I am trying to check if that holds without the symmetry of $V$.

Comment: I've confirmed empirically that the result does **not** hold for arbitrary positive semidefinite matrices $\mathcal L$. I suspect that the same is true for Laplacian matrices

Comment: Thank you so much for the counter-example! I think there is more structure into $V$ which could possibly help in proving the result needed. $V =(M\Sigma)^\top (M\Sigma) + \gamma M \Sigma$ with $M$ being an invertible matrix with positive eigenvalues, $\Sigma \succ 0$ is a diagonal matrix with positive diagonal elements, and $\gamma >0$.

Comment: Here is my attempt. Does it seem logical to you? We know that $\mathrm{null}(M\Sigma) = \varnothing$ since $\mathrm{det}(M\Sigma) = \mathrm{det}(M) \mathrm{det}(\Sigma) \neq 0$. Therefore, $(M\Sigma)^\top (M\Sigma) \succ 0$. Then, $\sigma \Big(-\mathcal{L}_\mathrm{dc}  (M\Sigma)^\top (M\Sigma) \Big) \in (-\infty, 0]$. Since $V$ is a continuous function in $\gamma$, then by continuity, there exists $\gamma^\star$ such that $\sigma \Big ( -\mathcal{L}_\mathrm{dc}  (M\Sigma)^\top (M\Sigma) - \gamma  \mathcal{L}_\mathrm{dc} M \Sigma \Big) \in (-\infty, 0]$ for $\gamma \in (0, \gamma^\star)$.

Comment: I don't see why continuity implies that there exists such a $\gamma^\star$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the first question is no. A randomly generated counterexample:

$$
\mathcal L = \left[\begin{matrix}2 & -1 & -1\\-1 & 2 & -1\\-1 & -1 & 2\end{matrix}\right], \quad 
V = \left[\begin{matrix}-58.337 & -432.225 & -100.272\\-29.695 & -206.429 & -48.576\\161.894 & 1158.166 & 270.765\end{matrix}\right].
$$
The entries of $V$ here are exact. The eigenvalues of $V$ are approximately $0.788, 2.129, 3.082$. The eigenvalues of $\mathcal L V$ are approximately $-705.188, 7.894, 0$.

Because $V$ is invertible, the number of zero eigenvalues in the product up to geometric (but not necessarily algebraic) multiplicity is equal to the number of zero eigenvalues in $\mathcal L$, which is equal to the number of connected components in the underlying graph.

For any given $\mathcal L$, it is necessarily possible to find an invertible $V$ for which the eigenvalues of the product $\mathcal L V$ are **all** equal to zero. I am not sure, however, if such a $V$ with only positive eigenvalues can be found.